# Italian citizen travelling in Japan for holiday. What to do?

Tags: visas, air-travel, japan, covid-19, italian-citizens

I am planning to visit Japan in late summer (for 1-2 weeks I am not sure yet). I am an Italian citizen with an Italian passport. I had a quick look online to see if I need to do anything regarding Visa.

To me it does not look like it, I should just be able to enter there for the period I have in mind. I don't know however if there's some covid restriction still applied and I need to do something in advance.

Any other info on the subject would be useful, I would be taking the flight from South Korea and coming back to South Korea (I don't know if this information is relevant but I am mentioning it anyway).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As stated [here](https://www.japan.travel/it/plan/visa-info/), as an Italian citizen, you don't need a visa to enter Japan. You will get a stamp on your passport and can stay in the country for tourism up to 90 days.

By using [this site](https://vjw-lp.digital.go.jp/en/howto/) you can complete the entry procedure before landing, and go through the immigration control at the airport quickly.

As stated also there

> Those entering Japan on or after April 29, 2023 are no longer required to present a valid vaccination certificate or pre-departure inspection certificate, and do not need to go through quarantine procedures via Visit Japan Web.
> Please note that you can continue to use Visit Japan Web after April 29, 2023, so please continue to use it for entry procedures as before.

Comment: Whilst I'm not Italian, I entered Japan yesterday and can confirm there are currently no Covid-based requirements for entering.